# How to change the order partial views are rendered in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My Layout file renders a partial view for the header and than renders the body after that.
Inside the controller action to render the body, I set some viewbag properties that I want to display in the header, but by the time the body action method runs, the header is already rendered so the header does not display the ViewBag properties.

Is there any way to have the header partial view render after the rest of the actions have executed?

Or can I put the "@Html.Partial("_Header")" line at the bottom of the Layout.cshtml file and use some sort of css or code to place the rendered html at the top of the layout?

Comment: It might work better to not depend on render ordering. Is there something preventing you from setting the `ViewBag` members in the controller?

Comment: They are currently being set in the body's controller.  But the header uses those viewbag members to display information.